# expand rows based using a series input- pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

i am looking to add a new column and multiply the number of lines in my df for a given series (ex..1,2,3,4)
for a given input that looks like below

```
[{"Name":"bruce","kills":0,"saves":60,"health":10,"energy":10},
{"Name":"clark","kills":25,"saves":100,"health":1000,"energy":10},
{"Name":"diana","kills":15,"saves":80,"health":100,"energy":10}]

Name    kills   saves   health  energy
bruce   0       60      10      10
clark   25      100     1000    10
diana   15      80      100     10
```

output should be below

```
Name    kills   saves   health  energy  Quater
bruce   0       60      10      10      1
bruce   0       60      10      10      2
bruce   0       60      10      10      3
bruce   0       60      10      10      4
clark   25      100     1000    10      1
clark   25      100     1000    10      2
clark   25      100     1000    10      3
clark   25      100     1000    10      4
diana   15      80      100     10      1
diana   15      80      100     10      2
diana   15      80      100     10      3
diana   15      80      100     10      4
```

is there any ways to achieve this in pandas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use, [`DataFrame.assign`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html) to create a new column `Quater` and assign this column a value from the sequence `1, 2, 3..`, then use [`pd.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) to concat the list of dataframes, then use [`DataFrame.sort_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) along with `ignore_index=True` to sort the dataframe:

```
df1 = pd.concat([df.assign(Quater=i) for i in range(1, 5)])
df1 = df1.sort_values(by=df1.columns.tolist(), ignore_index=True)
```

Result:

```
# print(df1)
     Name  kills  saves  health  energy  Quater
0   bruce      0     60      10      10       1
1   bruce      0     60      10      10       2
2   bruce      0     60      10      10       3
3   bruce      0     60      10      10       4
4   clark     25    100    1000      10       1
5   clark     25    100    1000      10       2
6   clark     25    100    1000      10       3
7   clark     25    100    1000      10       4
8   diana     15     80     100      10       1
9   diana     15     80     100      10       2
10  diana     15     80     100      10       3
11  diana     15     80     100      10       4
```